# Enable ASP classic logging to event log

Tags: iis, windows-event-log, asp-classic, asp, metabase

I thought my need was pretty simple, but I couldn't find a solution...

How can I make ASP-classic errors appear in Windows Event Log ?
I need it on Windows-server-2000 and Windows-Server-2003.

Regards,
Frédéric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Server 2003 (IIS 6) there is the Metabase property **AspErrorsToNTLog** (boolean).

See this Microsoft TechNet article: [AspErrorsToNTLog Metabase Property (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/ac2a9acb-5c06-4802-ac62-0f08e6815fd6.mspx?mfr=true).

> The AspErrorsToNTLog property
>   specifies which ASP errors are written
>   to the Windows event Log. ASP errors
>   are written to the client browser and
>   to the IIS log files by default.
>   AspErrorsToNTLog is set to FALSE by
>   default, and modifies the
>   AspLogErrorRequests property in the
>   following way: 
>   -  If
>   AspLogErrorRequests is set to FALSE,
>   then ASP errors are not written to the
>   Windows event log, regardless of the
>   value of AspErrorsToNTLog.
>
> - If
>     AspLogErrorRequests is set to TRUE,
>     then if IIS fails to write an item to
>     the IIS log file, the item is written
>     to the Windows event log as a warning,
>     regardless of the value of
>     AspErrorsToNTLog.
> - If
>     AspLogErrorRequests is set to TRUE and
>     AspErrorsToNTLog is set to FALSE, then
>     only the most serious ASP errors are
>     sent to the Windows event log. Serious
>     ASP errors are numbers 100, 101, 102,
>     103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 115, 190,
>     191, 192, 193, 194, 240, 241, and 242.
> - If AspLogErrorRequests is set to
>     TRUE and AspErrorsToNTLog is set to
>     TRUE, then all ASP errors are written
>     to the Windows event log.   Note This
>     property does not control logging
>     requests to the IIS log files. To
>     accomplish this see the LogType and
>     DontLog properties. Also, this
>     property does not control IIS Event
>     Messages, which are always sent to the
>     Windows event log. This property is a
>     process-level property. If this
>     property set at the Web service level,
>     it is applicable to all in-process
>     application keys. Metabase property
>     settings at the Web site level or
>     lower are ignored for in-process
>     applications unless the Web site key
>     is isolated as an out-of-process
>     application.

This article here explains how you can change the IIS metabase file in IIS 6: [Modify the IIS Metabase Directly (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1d1e5de4-fd63-40cd-bc5d-c20521548eed.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 1):

We're using this [AspEventlog component](http://www.alphasierrapapa.com/iisdev/components/aspeventlog/) on Windows Server 2003.